# UILabel - Wordwrap text

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uilabel, word-wrap

Is there any way to have a label wordwrap text as needed?  I have the line breaks set to word wrap and the label is tall enough for two lines, but it appears that it will only wrap on line breaks.  Do I have to add line breaks to make it wrap properly?  I just want it to wrap if it can't fit it in horizontally.

Answer (score 320, accepted):

If you set `numberOfLines` to 0 (and the label to word wrap), the label will automatically wrap and use as many of lines as needed.

If you're editing a `UILabel` in IB, you can enter multiple lines of text by pressing <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>  to get a line break - <kbd>return</kbd> alone will finish editing.

Comment: To clarify for noobs like myself, this would be: cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

Comment: In iOS 6 and later, use `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`, not `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`.

Comment: You might also need the following: label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: ```label.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping``` and 
    ```label.numberOfLines = 0``` in swift

Comment: This does not work for me in (Xcode 7.3, iOS 9.3). My label text is wrapping in the XCode UI, but in my app the text does not wrap. I've tried setting these props via GUI Attributes Inspector, and via Code, neither works.

Comment: For anyone who this wasn't obvious to (like me): The UILabel must have some sort of limit on its width (either from an actual width constraint or margin constraints); otherwise it won't wrap.

Comment: @jcady, that is an excellent point now that auto-layout is more common - if the labels width is allowed to expand as much as possible, it will stay on one line.  The label also must be allowed to expand in height though!

Comment: label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping in swift 3

Comment: Deprecated, now use `[label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]`

Answer (score 27):

`UILabel` has a property [`lineBreakMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620525-linebreakmode?language=objc) that you can set as per your requirement.

Comment: "I have the line breaks set to word wrap ".  This only wraps on actual line breaks, it won't automatically break once it is to long.

Answer (score 27):

In Swift you would do it like this:

```
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.numberOfLines = 0
```

(Note that the way the lineBreakMode constant works is different to in ObjC)

Comment: Care to elaborate on how it's different?

Comment: I think I meant just that the naming is different. It has probably changed again in swift3

Comment: Line break mode should be set to word wrapping be default

Comment: @MobileMonin my experience that is not always the case. Maybe IB changes it in some circumstances?

Comment: label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping in Obj C

Comment: With Swift 4 I had to use NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

Answer (score 4):

**Xcode 10, Swift 4**

Wrapping the Text for a label can also be done on Storyboard by selecting the Label, and using Attributes Inspector.

**Lines** = *0* 
**Linebreak** = *Word Wrap*

[image]

Comment: Using a branBrand-New label, directly adding it to the view, this still generates a single-line label (with a width larger than the phone's width) for me, despite setting lines to 0 and linebreak to Word Wrap. Is there another setting that could be needed? Do I need to attach additional code?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 12.5.1, Swift 5.

I found that even though I had **Lines = 0** and **LineBreak = Word Wrap** set, it still didn't wrap the long label text.  Double check your label constraints in IB (or wherever you set them).

I found that sometimes IB tries to fix the constraint settings and adds a >= or <= constraint for leading and trailing edges.

This label constraint will not wrap the text:

[image]

But this will:

[image]

Notice the >= on the Label.trailing edge in the first picture.  Set this to = and the text should wrap.